# Is it possible that no baggage is free for a flight?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, bookings, flight-search-engines

I searched on skyscanner for a flight and I booked it using trip.com because it was the cheapest option suggested by the search engine.

I paid and I received an e-mail with my booking and it says:

> Baggage Allowance
>
> [FREE]No free baggage allowance.Please contact
>   airline for detailed baggage regulations.

This is the file I received:

[image]

I took a look on [their website](https://www.latam.com/en_us/travel-information/baggage/carry-on-baggage/) and it says that:

> You can take one suitcase and a personal item with you, free of
>   charge, under your care and responsibility. Your carry-on-baggage must
>   be light enough that you can place it in the overhead compartment
>   without needing help.
>
> We remind you that cabin space is limited and we can place your
>   baggage in the hold free of charge.

I'm not sure which is the truth. I'm planning to take only a small bag with me, something that can be put under the chair in front, I never heard of an air company to charge you for that.

Does anyone know how the things really are?

Comment: Anything is possible these days however very unlikely that you cannot carry a small personal item.

Comment: I believe this may be the same as Basic Economy. They allow a personal item but everything else needs to be bought. If you have the PNR issued, you can check your personal allowance by clicking on Manage your trip (https://www.latam.com/en_us/apps/personas/mybookings).

Comment: Do they simply mean no _checked_ baggage, i.e. the large bag where you put through the long conveyor belt system before you go through security/immigration, included?

Comment: @B.Liu:  Yes, I think so.  LATAM also has a separate page concerning [checked bags](https://www.latam.com/en_us/travel-information/baggage/checked-baggage/), in which it's clear that "Promo Economy" and "Light Economy" class fares do not receive a free checked baggage allowance.

Comment: I know of at least one airline that sells tickets where carry-on bags (not small enough to be considered "personal items") incur an extra charge:  [Spirit Airlines](https://www.spirit.com/OptionalServices), a low-cost carrier in the USA.

Comment: Traditionally the term "baggage allowance" referred to checked luggage only, so that's probably what's meant in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Indeed this is possible and it is more common on the basic of airlines wanting to advertise or show a lower fare. Sometimes it is called *Economy Basic* or another name to distinguish it from an other level of *Economy*.

Most airlines still allow a carry-on plus personal item but again this varies. Some only allow a single item, while others now charge for a carry on even. This of course makes your ticket cost more at a later time than the purchasing time. Sometimes you can a warning when purchasing a ticket but sometimes you find out later.

In the case shown, it is referring to *Checked* baggage but both a carry-on and a personal item are allowed. There is another question on this site about which airline does not allow both a carry-on and personal item LATAM is not one of those at this time. Always double check with your ticket and call the airline when in doubt because rules can change any time.

Answer (score 4):

You presumably purchased an economy fare for domestic flights within Argentina.

These fares do not include any **checked/hold** baggage as described here:
[Checked](https://www.latam.com/en_us/travel-information/baggage/checked-baggage/)

LATAM allows 1 carry-on and 1 personal item on all fares as described here: [Carry-on](https://www.latam.com/en_us/travel-information/baggage/carry-on-baggage/)